# re-expand groupby data pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a following data after df.groupby(). Each element is separated by tab:

```
Num one two three
Alp A B
```

Is it possible to revert the groupby to melt format ?

```
Col1 Col2
Num  one
Num  two
Num  three
Alp  A
Alp  B
```

Thanks in advance.

AP

Comment: `Num one two three` are columns?

Comment: so it is one column?

Comment: Yes. Edited it to improve clarity. I have groupbyed it to join by tab

Comment: No. This will be a tab limited file. So when I re-input in pandas, Num will be in col1, one in col2, two in col3 ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print (df)
  col1 col2 col3   col4
0  Num  one  two  three
1  Alp    A    B    NaN
```

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('col1').stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index(name='col2')
print (df1)
  col1   col2
0  Num    one
1  Num    two
2  Num  three
3  Alp      A
4  Alp      B
```

Or [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), but for remove `NaNs` add [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df2 = df.melt('col1', value_name='col2').drop('variable', 1).dropna(subset=['col2'])
print (df2)
  col1   col2
0  Num    one
1  Alp      A
2  Num    two
3  Alp      B
4  Num  three
```

Comment: This means, I have to keep them in 1 column?

Comment: No, not necessary.

Comment: will dropna remove the entire Alp right ? It is not desired. set_index+unstack method seems apt !

Comment: dropna remone NaNs if in data.